# Create alias for sender's email in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, actionmailer

I have setup smtp_settings like this

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.anything.com",
    port: 465,
    authentication: :login,
    user_name: "my_name@anything.com",
    password: "my_password",
    domain: "anything.com",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

When I send any email from app, it shows the sender's email as `my_name@anything.com`.

**What I want to do is to create alias for my email.** For ex:

```
alias_email = 'xyz123@abc.com'
actual_email = 'my_name@anything.com'
```

**Now I want the sender's email to be visible as `xyz123@abc.com`, when anyone receives that email.**

I tried searching a lot, but couldn't find any solution. May be I don't know what this thing called (alias for email) and doing wrong search.

[update]

I tried `mail( from: "xyz123@abc.com", to: "abc@email.com", subject: "Hello!" )` but it gives sender's email address as `my_name@anything.com`.

**Note:** Previously I thought, this couldn't be possible, but then I have seen at couple of sites, where they asked my email and when any of my customer purchases, they send them email with my email address as sender's address.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Using gmail smtp you will get this as it is free use Sendgrid

Answer (score 3):

This can not be done through Google SMTP. Google **automatically rewrites** the From line of any email you send via its SMTP server to the default send mail as email address in your Gmail or Google Apps email account Settings.

Here is how to specify a from address in your `ActionMailer` class

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   # either a default from address
   default from: "John Doe <noreply@example.com>"

   # or specified inside a specific method
   def confirmation_instructions(user_id)
      @user = User.find user_id
      mail(from: "Confirmation <confirm@example.com>",subject: "Confirmation Instructions", to: "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email>}") do |format|
      format.html :layout => false
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: I tried with different domains too, but same results.  Anyway thanks for your answer, I will try Sendgrid or Mandrill and update.